# Make items disappear in beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, itemize

I want to show three items to evaluate the features of each one and then select one of them, so I need to show all of them first and then I need that two of them disappear, or at list become transparent. How can I do that?

**Edit: (by Sigur)**

Those answers were really helpful, but I have 3 items with several subitems in 3 columns. The method number 2 works with the subitems, but when I try to use it with the items, the tex has errors `(missing } or \endgroup)`.

This is the code:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\LARGE{TITLE}}
%   \vspace{4pt}
    \begin{itemize}
    \leftmarginii=0.8\leftmargini\relax
        \begin{columns}[t]
            \column{0.3\textwidth}
            \item<1> Item1:
                \begin{itemize}
                    \justifying
                    \vspace{4pt}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem1}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem2}
                \end{itemize}
            \column{0.3\textwidth}
            \item<1-2> Item2:
                \begin{itemize}
                    \justifying
                    \vspace{4pt}
                    \item<1-2> \footnotesize{Subitem1}
                    \item<1-2> \footnotesize{Subitem2}
                \end{itemize}
            \column{0.3\textwidth}
            \item<1> Item3:
                \begin{itemize}
                    \justifying
                    \vspace{4pt}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem1}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem2}
                \end{itemize}
        \end{columns}   
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

The new code:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\LARGE{Title}}
    Antena para recepción APT
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.27\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            %\leftmarginii=0.8\leftmargini\relax
            \item<1> Antena Yagi:
            \begin{itemize}
                %\justifying
                \vspace{4pt}
                \item<1>[\color{red}\ding{55}] \footnotesize{Requiere un sistema de seguimiento por ser directiva.}
                \item<1>[\color{verde}\ding{51}] \footnotesize{Ganancia alta ($>$10 dB). Incrementable si se añaden más elementos.}
                \item<1>[\color{red}{\ding{55}}] \footnotesize{Polarización lineal.}
                \item<1>[\color{red}{\ding{55}}] \footnotesize{Gran tamaño y carga al viento.}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}      

    \begin{minipage}[t]{.29\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            %\leftmarginii=0.8\leftmargini\relax
            \item<1-2> Antena QHA:
            \begin{itemize}
                %\justifying
                \vspace{4pt}
                \item<1-2>[\color{verde}\ding{51}] \footnotesize{No se necesita un sistema de seguimiento al ser poco directiva.} 
                \item<1-2>[\color{red}{\ding{55}}] \footnotesize{Ganancia baja ($<$5 dB).} 
                \item<1-2>[\color{verde}\ding{51}] \footnotesize{Polarización circular.}
                \item<1-2>[\color{verde}\ding{51}] \footnotesize{Anchura reducida.}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{.29\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            %\leftmarginii=0.8\leftmargini\relax
            \item<1> Antena DCA:
            \begin{itemize}
                %\justifying
                \vspace{4pt}
                \item<1>[\color{verde}\ding{51}] \footnotesize{No se necesita un sistema de seguimiento al ser poco directiva.}
                \item<1>[\color{red}{\ding{55}}] \footnotesize{Ganancia baja (Entre 4 y 6 dB).}  
                \end{itemize}   
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just specify the slides on which you want things to appear.

## Method 1: Relative Overlay Specifications

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+> First
        \item<.-+>Second
        \item<+(-2)>Third
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`+` increments the overlay count which `beamer` uses to track things. `.` specifies the current slide. `n-m` specifies a range i.e. slides `n` to `m` inclusive. `n` and `m` can be numbers (absolute specifications e.g. slide `1` or slide `3`) or variations on the `+`, `.` etc. (relative specifications e.g. this slide `.` or the next slide `+`). `+(n)` tells `beamer` to increment the count and add `n`. `n` may be negative or positive.

So the above increments the count, putting the first item on slide `1` (as opposed to `0` which would not be shown); shows the second item from the current slide which is now `1` to the next slide `2`; and finally shows the third item on slide `1` (because the `+` increments the number to `3` but the `(-2)` decreases it by 2 and 3-2=`1`).

## Method 2: Absolute Overlay Specifications

For simple cases, it is often easier to just tell `beamer` which slides to use directly rather than worrying about relative specifications. For example, the following is equivalent to the above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> First
        \item<1-2>Second
        \item<1>Third
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Invisibility]

## Transparency

If you would prefer to show the covered items as transparent simply add

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

to your preamble. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> First
        \item<1-2>Second
        \item<1>Third
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: With transparency]

Answer (score 1):

A simple possible solution. You can improve it, ifyou wish.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1> Only at 1st slide
\item<1> Also only at 1st slide
\item<1-2> At 1st and 2nd slide
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

```
\begin{frame}
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
%                    \justifying
                    \vspace{4pt}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem1}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem2}
                \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
%                    \justifying
                    \vspace{4pt}
                    \item<1-2> \footnotesize{Subitem1}
                    \item<1-2> \footnotesize{Subitem2}
                \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
%                    \justifying
                    \vspace{4pt}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem1}
                    \item<1> \footnotesize{Subitem2}
                \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```