# Beamer - Make Overlaid tikzpicture Disappear

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Say that I have a frame in Beamer like this (where I load the table from an external file):

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table Name}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{c | cccc}
\input{\dir/table}

\pause \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (2.5,1.3) rectangle (3.4,4.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pause \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1.5,1.3) rectangle (2.4,4.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

My goal is to highlight two different areas of the table with the overlaid tikzpicture's. I don't want the first highlight (or second) to appear until I advance the slide. When I advance it, I only want the first to appear and not the second. When I advance it again, I only want the second to appear, and not the first. The `\pause` command gets me a lot of mileage, and I think the main issue is having the first highlight disappear when I am on the last slide and only want the second highlight.

Does the answer have to do with?: 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

and

this: [Make items disappear in beamer presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188231/make-items-disappear-in-beamer-presentations)

As requested, a MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table Name}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{c | cccc}
A          &       B&        C&   D\\
\hline
1                   &        1&       6&       7\\
2                   &         2&       5&       8\\
Total               &        3&      4&        9    \\

\pause \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pause \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1,3) rectangle (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TikZ drawing macros are overlay-aware, so you can do something like the example below. `\draw<2> ..` means that `\draw` is only shown on the second slide.

Note that in your example the `table` environment is not really necessary. In a `beamer` presentation, it's only needed if you want to have a `\caption`. And for that matter, since a `table` is not a float in `beamer` (that wouldn't make sense), the float placement options (`[htpb]`) doesn't do anything.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table Name}
\begin{tabular}{c | cccc}
A          &       B&        C&   D\\
\hline
1                   &        1&       6&       7\\
2                   &         2&       5&       8\\
Total               &        3&      4&        9  
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw<2>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw<3>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1,3) rectangle (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You might be interested in the `tikzmark` library though. The `\tikzmark{<name>}` macro allows you to make a marker in the table (or any other text). You can use that as a coordinate with `(pic cs:<name>)`. Note that the `tikzpicture` needs the options `[remember picture,overlay]`.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table Name}
\begin{tabular}{c | cccc}
A                   &   \tikzmark{a}B&      C&   D\\
\hline
1                   &     1&    6\tikzmark{b}&       7\\
2                   &     2&      \tikzmark{c}5&       8\\
Total               &     3&      4&        9\tikzmark{d}  
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<2>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] ([shift={(-2pt,12pt)}]pic cs:a) rectangle ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:b);
    \draw<2>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] ([shift={(-2pt,12pt)}]pic cs:c) rectangle ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to draw the same tikzpicture *outside* of the tabular environment?

Comment: @bill999 Yes. Just move it outside. I added an addendum to my answer by the way.